# Удалить последний элемент массива

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Парсером Simple HTML DOM получаю массив:

`$otveti_utf8_o = $doc->find(".message");`

этот массив вывожу в обратном порядке:

`$otveti_utf8 = array_reverse($otveti_utf8_o);`

Теперь мне нужно удалить последний элемент из этого массива.
Пытался делать с помощью функции **array_pop**:

```
$otveti_utf8_o = $doc->find(".message");
$otveti_utf8_a = array_reverse($otveti_utf8_o);
$otveti_utf8 = array_pop($otveti_utf8_a);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($otveti_utf8); $i++) { //удаляю первый элемент
    echo $otveti_utf8[$i]."<hr />";
}
```

ошибка:

> Cannot use object of type simple_html_dom_node as array in

Как удалить последний элемент массива в моем случае?

Comment: Вам прямым текстом пишет, что это не массив, то есть вам для начала надо привести к массиву ваш результат, а уже потом удалять

Comment: @СашаБоричевский но а `$otveti_utf8_o = $doc->find(".message");` - это массив. почему тогда `otveti_utf8_a ` уже не массив?

Comment: посмотрите для начала var_dump обоих переменных. то, что array_reverse сработал еще ни разу не значит, что в переменной массив

Comment: array_pop возвращает удаленный элемент а не сам массив, т.е. $otveti_utf8 это тот самый элемент

Answer (score 2):

все дело во невнимательности. ошибка возникает не при удалении элемента массива.

вы удалили элемент

```
$otveti_utf8 = array_pop($otveti_utf8_a);
```

и на данном этапе ошибок никаких  нет. Ошибка возникает в следующий строке:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($otveti_utf8); $i++) {
```

а более конкретно - при попытке вызвать `count($otveti_utf8)`, вместо, очевидно, `count($otveti_utf8_a)`.
В связи с этим и такое сообщение об ошибке, что вместо массива передан объект класса `simple_html_dom_node` (то есть извлеченный элемент)